# How can I use regex find-and-replace to insert missing spaces before curly braces?

Tags: css, regex, sass, regexp-replace

I have an SCSS file, for example:

```css
.nice{
  display: flex;

  &--green {
    color: green;
  }

  &--2{
    display: grid;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I would like to insert a space before opening curly braces where the space is missing. How can I do it using regex find-and-replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in the cases where we have nested `&`, it will always be followed by at least 1 letter, number, hyphen or underscore, as per [CSS grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner). We also need to consider media queries, in which case it will be a `)` before the `{` character.

So, I believe this should cover all cases:

Replace: `([a-zA-Z0-9-_\)]+)(\s*)(\{)`
With: `$1 $3`
(Where `$1` represents the first matching group, etc.)